# Unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is contractible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $\mathcal{T}_{\infty}= \left\{ U \subset \mathbb{R}^{\infty}: \ U \cap \mathbb{R}^n \in \mathcal{T}_n, \text{ for } n=1,2,... \right\} $.
Of course $\mathcal{T}_{\infty}$ is topology in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$. How to prove that $S^{\infty} = \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty} : \ \|v\|=1 \}$ is contractible?

:)

Can we find homeomorphism without fixed point from $D^{\infty} = \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^{\infty} : \ \|v\| \le 1 \}$ onto $D^{\infty}$? I was trying to find such homeomorphism, but I failed...

Comment: Is $\mathcal{T}_n$ the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$?  In what sense do you mean $U \cap \mathbb{R}^n$, since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$?  And most importantly, what is the norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is a set of sequences $(a_1,a_2,...)$ where only finite number of coordinates $\neq 0$, and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is set of $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n,0,0,...)$. The norm is $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i^2}$.

Comment: You second question is answered rather easily by considering the shift map $\sigma\colon D^{\infty}\rightarrow D^{\infty}$ given by $\sigma (x_0,x_1,x_2\ldots)=(0,x_0,x_1,x_2\ldots)$. Can you see why the image of $\sigma$ is homeomorphic to $D^{\infty}$?

Comment: You need to explain in the question what you mean by $\Bbb R^\infty$, since your intended meaning is not the usual meaning of the symbol.

Comment: @Daniel: The right-shift map doesn’t meet the OP’s requirement that it map $D^\infty$ **onto** $D^\infty$.

Comment: You're right. It also doesn't even match the criteria that it has no fixed points as $(0,0,\ldots)$ is clearly fixed. The left shift map satisfies the onto requirement, but not the fixed point.

Comment: Also: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119362/unit-sphere-in-r-infty-is-contractible

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459397

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You'll find a proof that the infinite dimensional sphere is contractible on page 88 of Allen Hatcher's [Algebraic Topology](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf) kindly hosted for free by him on his website.

The proof gives an explicit homotopy between the identity map and the constant map on the sphere $S^{\infty}$.

Let $f_t\colon\mathbb{R}^{\infty}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ be given by $f_t(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(1-t)(x_1,x_2,\ldots)+t(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$. For all $t\in[0,1]$, this map sends nonzero points to nonzero points, so $f_t/|f_t|$ is a homotopy from the identity map on $S^{\infty}$ to the map $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\mapsto (0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$. We then define a homotopy from this map to the constant map at $(1,0,0,\ldots)$ by setting $g_t(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(1-t)(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)+t(1,0,0,\ldots)$. The homotopy is then given by $g_t/|g_t|$. The composition of these two homotopies then gives a homotopy from the identity map to the constant map, and so $S^{\infty}$ is contractible.

Comment: Sorry I missed a bracket around the $1-t$, and thanks for pointing out the typo in Allen's name :).

Comment: Thank you Daniel, Brian and Nate :) I'm sorry for my requirements but I don't get for example why $f(t)/|f(t)|$ is a homotopy (of course why it's contiuous)? Can you give me a hint? Thanks :)

Comment: Hopefully you agree that $f_t$ is continuous (this is common construction of a homotopy - for example the usual homotopy from the punctured plane to the circle). You should also be happy with the fact that $f_t(\alpha x)=\alpha f_t(x)$ holds for real numbers $\alpha$ and so $f_t$ preserves lines going though the origin (kind of like a rotation in the plane). Finally, you should also be happy that if $|x|=1$, then $|f_t(x)|=1$ and so $f_t$ is well defined if we restrict it to the sphere of radius 1. Restriction of a continuous map to a subspace is also continuous and so we're done.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to show this is to note that a basis of the topology of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is given by all balls $B_{r}(x)=\{y: ||x-y||<r\}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ and $r>0$ and then observe that $f_t$ sends all open balls to open balls for all $t$ (small exercise, but note that because $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is a topological group, you only need to look at balls with center at the origin $(0,0,\ldots)$) and in an injective way. It follows that the inverse image of a basis element is a basis element and so $f_t$ must be continuous.

Comment: Hi Daniel, wonderful answer, thank you. But how can you make sure that $g_t \neq 0$? Thank you~

Comment: @Jellyfish If $g_t(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=0$ then $(t,(1-t)x_1,(1-t)x_2,\ldots)=0$ and so $t=0$ and $x_i=0$ for all $i\geq 1$ but then $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\notin S^{\infty}$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Dear @DanielRust, yes that is what I followed. But I am worried about $x_n$. Since $i$ only runs till $n-1$?

Comment: @Jellyfish the element $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\in S^{\infty}$ is an *infinite* tuple of points $x_i\in[-1,1]$ so $i$ 'runs' over all natural numbers, and so there's no '$n$'. It's precisely because of this that we can use the above argument, and why such an argument would **not** work for any of the finite dimensional spheres.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much @DanielRust!!

Comment: actually I don't agree that it's clear that this homotopy is continuous. Where does one ever use the topology on $S^\infty$ and also the product topology on $S^\infty$?

Comment: You're using the subspace topology on $\mathbb R^\infty$, not a product topology (except for the product topology on $\mathbb R^\infty$ I guess). The maps are continuous in each coordinate quite obviously as we're just working with the shift map, scaling and coordinate-wise addition, so the map itself is continuous by the universal property of products.

Answer (score 12):

We may notice that $\mathbb{S}^{\infty}= \bigcup\limits_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{S}^n$ where $\mathbb{S}^n$ is included into $\mathbb{S}^{n+1}$ thanks to $$(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto (x_1, \dots, x_n,0).$$ In particular, $\mathbb{S}^n$ is a subcomplex of $\mathbb{S}^{n+1}$ (this construction is also described in Hatcher's book).

Because attaching a $m$-cell [does not change](http://darkwing.uoregon.edu/~botvinn/sec11.ps) the $n$-th homotopy group when $m>n$, we deduce that $$\pi_n( \mathbb{S}^{\infty})= \pi_n(\mathbb{S}^{n+1})= 0, \ \forall n \geq 1.$$

According to [Whitehead theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem), a [weakly contractible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_contractible) CW complex is contractible. Therefore, $\mathbb{S}^{\infty}$ is contractible.

Of course, the proof given by Daniel Rust is much more elementary, but I find interesting to see how adding cells kills successively the homotopy groups in order to make $\mathbb{S}^{\infty}$ contractible.

Comment: you might like to see the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131453)

Comment: "Attaching $m$-cell to a CW complex $X$ does not change $\pi _n(X)$ with $m>n$". Is this conclusion comes from Cellular approximation theorem? Or is there any obvious way to show this fact?

Comment: It is Corollary 4.12 in Hatcher's book. He uses indeed the cellular approximation for pairs.

Comment: No cellular approximation theorem necessary:  $\pi_n(S^\infty)=\pi_n(colim S^\infty)=colim \pi_n(S^\infty)=colim 0=0$.